# setIgnoredWords method in UITextChecker

Tags: objective-c, ios6, spell-checking

I want my app to ignore an array of words and not treat them as "misspelt" words.
I came across the setIgnoredWords method in the [UITextChecker Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , but I am not able to figure out how to use it.

It would be really great if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
[UITextChecker learnWord:@"myWordWhichMustNotBeChecked"];
```

put your word there. You can always check of your word is ignored by:

```
if ([UITextChecker hasLearnedWord::@"myWordWhichMustNotBeChecked"])
```

and unlearn it by:

```
[UITextChecker unlearnWord:@"myWordWhichMustNotBeChecked"];
```

Comment: well. the problem is I have about 65000 words and learning all the words using the learnWord function is taking way too much time.

Comment: This means you need to check manually from your list as the user inputs next letters. To shorten that time, you may have construct an indexed table with indices for first and second letters in the word. Does your dictionary changes in time?

Comment: I may have not explained properly. If I use the learnWord function, it would add words to the iOS dictionary on that device. If I go that route and want to add about 65000 words, it is taking way too long.

Comment: Well the best that comes to my mind in this case is to make your own TextChecker unless it is a way to add whole dictionary at once.